# Informatica power center download fails on personal laptop

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to download Informatica power center through oracle eDelivery, following all the steps and starts downloading but the download never gets completed and fails after few hours with network error. Has anyone faced the similar issue and how to resolve and get the download successful.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to Informatica PowerCenter itself. Try different machine and then move the data using USB stick or something.